# MySQL query update on join error 1292

Tags: mysql, join

This is an sql query try in MySql database tables where `join` two different tables for extract the value of `PR_Cod` and `PR_Cod` for single user:

```
SELECT
    CA.theDate,
    CA.theHour,
    CA.TheUSerCode,
    A.PR_Cod,
    A.PR_Name
FROM
    tblUserRegistered CA
JOIN tblUserAreaGlobal A ON A.TheUSerCode = CA.TheUSerCode
WHERE
    theDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-11-16', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND '2015-11-16'
AND (
    HOUR (theHour) >= '15:00:00'
    OR HOUR (theHour) <= '03:00:00'
)
AND A.PR_Cod IN ('058')
ORDER BY
    CA.TheUSerCode,
    CA.theDate,
    CA.theHour;

+------------+----------+-------------+--------+---------+
| theDate    | theHour  | TheUSerCode | PR_Cod | PR_Name |
+------------+----------+-------------+--------+---------+
| 2015-11-16 | 21:30:37 | EU4012111   | 058    | XXX1    |
| 2015-11-16 | 22:21:29 | EU4012111   | 058    | XXX1    |
| 2015-11-16 | 15:15:00 | EU4046905   | 058    | XXX1    |
+------------+----------+-------------+--------+---------+
3 rows in set
```

Now I need update these three rows on fields `Value` and `Text` on the first table `tblUserRegistered`.

And I have tried this `update join` query:

```
UPDATE tblUserRegistered AS target
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
    CA.theDate,
    CA.theHour,
    CA.TheUSerCode,
    A.PR_Cod,
    A.PR_Name
FROM
    tblUserRegistered CA
JOIN tblUserAreaGlobal A ON A.TheUSerCode = CA.TheUSerCode
WHERE
    theDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-11-16', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND '2015-11-16'
AND (
    HOUR (theHour) >= '15:00:00'
    OR HOUR (theHour) <= '03:00:00'
)
AND A.PR_Cod IN ('058')
ORDER BY
    CA.TheUSerCode,
    CA.theDate,
    CA.theHour) AS source ON source.TheUSerCode = target.TheUSerCode
SET target.Value = 1,
 target.Text = 'Y';
```

But in output I don't have update only three rows extract with first query but more one row:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+-------+------+
| theDate    | theHour  | TheUSerCode | Value | Text |
+------------+----------+-------------+-------+------+
| 2015-11-16 | 22:21:29 | EU4012111   |     1 | Y    |
| 2015-11-16 | 21:30:37 | EU4012111   |     1 | Y    |
| 2015-11-16 | 15:15:00 | EU4046905   |     1 | Y    |
| 2015-11-16 | 04:22:13 | EU4046905   |     1 | Y    |
+------------+----------+-------------+-------+------+
4 rows in set
```

Why the query update the row with hour `04:22:13` ?

I have tried with:

```
UPDATE tblUserRegistered AS target
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
    CA.theDate,
    CA.theHour,
    CA.TheUSerCode,
    A.PR_Cod,
    A.PR_Name
FROM
    tblUserRegistered CA
JOIN tblUserAreaGlobal A ON A.TheUSerCode = CA.TheUSerCode
WHERE
    theDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-11-16', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND '2015-11-16'
AND (
    HOUR (theHour) >= '15:00:00'
    OR HOUR (theHour) <= '03:00:00'
)
AND A.PR_Cod IN ('058')
ORDER BY
    CA.TheUSerCode,
    CA.theDate,
    CA.theHour) AS source ON source.TheUSerCode = target.TheUSerCode
SET target.Value = 1,
 target.Text = 'Y'
    WHERE
        target.theDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-11-16', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND '2015-11-16'
    AND (
        HOUR (target.theHour) >= '15:00:00'
        OR HOUR (target.theHour) <= '03:00:00'
    )
    AND source.PR_Cod IN ('058');
```

But in this case I have error:

```
[Err] 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '15:00:00'
```

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You complicate yourself,simply take your query and use the UPDATE Syntax

```
UPDATE tblUserRegistered CA
JOIN tblUserAreaGlobal A 
ON A.TheUSerCode = CA.TheUSerCode
SET CA.Value = 1,
 CA.Text = 'Y'
WHERE
    theDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-11-16', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND '2015-11-16'
AND (
    HOUR (theHour) >= '15:00:00'
    OR HOUR (theHour) <= '03:00:00'
)
AND A.PR_Cod IN ('058')
```